# What is nonpersistent entity in guidewire and how can we create it?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

How many types of entities we have in PolicyCenter? What are those?
What is nonpersistent entity in policyCenter?
How can we create it?

Please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-persistent entity is a temporary entity that PC creates and uses only during the time that the PC server is running. When the server shuts down, PC discards the entity data. It is not possible to commit a non-persistent entity object to the database.
A non-persistent entity has to live in a bundle and can only live in one bundle. To create a temporary entity, it  is marked with an attribute of temporary="true".

Hope, it helps.